# Use database query for report title

Tags: jasper-reports

Is it possible in *JasperReports* to run a simple DB query to get a field for the title of the report. For example, the report is a customer price list, and there is a user parameter to enter "Customer ID #:". The report itself is a query from the price tables, I would like to retrieve the customer name from the customer table to put on in the header. I am using *iReport* to design the report.